# How to call abstract Inner class methods, in another class?

Tags: java, class, abstract

I have a problem with the following code:

```
public class ClassOut {

    abstract class ClassIn{

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Value: " + getValue());
        }

        double value = 20.5;
        public abstract double getValue();
    }
}
```

I have another class with the main method, and I want to print the value variable from the abstract Inner class "`abstract class ClassIn`".

Maybe it works with an anonymous class?

Comment: Why does the abstract class have a value field as well as an abstract getter?

Comment: You can create [Anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) or extend the abstract class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it works with an anonymous class as well.

```
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassOut out = new ClassOut();
        ClassOut.ClassIn ob = out.new ClassIn() {

            @Override
            public double getValue() {
                return super.value;
            }
        };

        ob.print();
    }
}

class ClassOut{
    abstract class ClassIn{

        public void print() {

            System.out.println("Value: " + getValue());
        }

        double value = 20.5;
        public abstract double getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a method on an abstract class. You have to have a *concrete* class deriving from this, an instance of that, and then call on that. e.g.

```
class ConcreteClassIn extends ClassIn {
   public double getValue() {
      return 0.0;
   }
}
ConcreteClassIn cc = new ConcreteClassIn ();
cc.getValue();
```

I note your comment re. anonymous classes. It will work with anonymous classes, just like the above, except that you won't have a name for the concrete class (hence *anonymous*) and so you can't use that derivation in multiple places.

Comment: good answer developing here@Brian ..you@AM3 could (if you can) make everything static(!) and call that (also on abstract).

Answer (score 1):

To use an inner class member variable,you will have to instantiate it

```
Outer.Inner oi = o.new Inner();
oi.member = 10;
```

And since you cannot instantiate an abstract class,you will have to create a concrete class to use it's member.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassOut co = new ClassOut();
co.new ClassIn() {
    @Override
    public abstract double getValue() {
        return 42;
    }
}.print();
```

A `new` instead of `co.new` would suffice when ClassIn would be `static`.
`value` might better be `protected` to be accessible in the child class.

Answer (score 0):

```
- You can not call a method on an abstract class. 
- You have to have create concrete class deriving from this class.
- Create instance of that derived class and then call method. 

e.g.

class ConcreteClass extends InnerClass 
{
   public double getValue() {
      return 0.0;
   }
}

ConcreteClass cc = new ConcreteClass ();
cc.getValue();
```